# How to create a Pull request CI/CD trigger on certain file changes only?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, gitlab, devops, google-cloud-build

In CI/CD, I would like to know if it's possible to create a Pull request CI/CD trigger, that runs on changes to specific files/folders only?
I know that google cloud build does not support this(some other popular tools do not support too). If that's the case, then what can be my alternates?

Answer (score 3):

This is not the complete answer but few cents from me, can you put a check into some shell script to look for a path/file from workspace in Jenkins or whatever build tool u are using, if that path/file is part of git commit then proceed with build.

Comment: Thank you! :) 
Looking for a path/file is good but I must look for changes on these files. Because the path/file will definitely always be there. But I want to trigger the PR pipeline only if the file changes. I am not sure, how I can check that.

Comment: I meant, if that file is part of latest commit.

Comment: Nice, I get it! But this would mean that PR trigger will first start and then check this file in the latest commit and if yes, continue with the next steps. Did I understand it correct?

Comment: You can use a `changeset` condition in jenkinsfile to check if files were changed in last commit: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/. But yes, the PR will be created already